# How to reduce web page load time

Tags: ss

I am running a selenium java maven project in Intelj ideada. I had to change my internet service provider due to moving. I was running my project without any problems in my old internet service provider (superonline). When I run my project in my new internet service provider (turkish telecom-ttnet), the loading times of the web pages can take up to 1 minute, sometimes not loading at all. When I connect my cell phone internet to the laptop, my project runs smoothly. The problem is not in my project, but I can't understand what the problem is. Can you help me?

When I connected the laptop to the cell phone internet, my project worked. Frankly, I don't understand network connection and modem settings, I think the problem is caused by the new ISP.

Comment: It is out of the scope of StackOverflow, provided that it is not a problem of Selenium.